# How to inherit methods that return a reference to the current object?

Tags: c++, inheritance

There is a base class

```
class LineEditItem
{
public:
    LineEditItem(QLineEdit* le, const Values_t& values = Values_t()):
        values(values),
        le(le)
    {}
    LineEditItem &addValue(int v, const QString &s)
    {
        values[v] = s;
        return *this;
    }
    LineEditItem &addValues(const Values_t& vals)
    {
        for (auto key: vals.keys())
        {
            values[key] = vals[key];
        }
        return *this;
    }
    void setValue(uint32_t v)
    {
        QString str;
        if (values.contains(v))
        {
            str = values[v];
        }
        else
        {
            str = "";
        }
        le->setText(str);
    }
    void clearValue()
    {
        le->clear();
    }

protected:
    Values_t values;
    QLineEdit* le;
};
```

There is a child class that must inherit the addValue and addValues methods

```
class LineEditItemBits: public LineEditItem
{
public:
    LineEditItemBits(QLineEdit* le, int begin, int end, const Values_t& values = Values_t()):
        LineEditItem(le, values),
        begin(begin),
        end(end)
    {}
    void setValue(uint32_t v)
    {
        int s = end - begin + 1;
        v = (v >> begin) & ((1 << s) - 1);
        LineEditItem::setValue(v);
    }
    LineEditItemBits &addValue(int v, const QString &s)
    {
        LineEditItem::addValue(v, s);
        return *this;
    }
    LineEditItemBits &addValues(const Values_t& vals)
    {
        LineEditItem::addValues(vals);
        return *this;
    }
private:
    int begin;
    int end;
};
```

But you have to explicitly prescribe these methods and call base class methods from them.
How to inherit these methods from the base class so that they return a reference to the child class?

Comment: Fluent interfaces interact badly with inheritance. You can't improve on what you have here.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you are trying to override these functions, so you should make them `virtual` in parent class.

Comment: @altE4 No, I wanted to leave them from the parent class, but then they return a reference to the parent class. ```auto l = QList<LineEditItemBits>() << LineEditItemBits().addValues(v1).addValues(v2) << LineEditItemBits().addValues(v1).addValues(v2)```.